# Is this a valid proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, roots, radicals, irrational-numbers

According to this [math.stackexchange thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166859/prove-show-that-a-number-is-square-if-and-only-if-its-prime-decomposition-contai)

A number is a perfect square if and only if its prime factorization contains only even exponents.

The prime factorization of $2 = 2^1$.

Therefore, the prime factorization of $2$ contains an odd exponent so $2$ is not a perfect square.

Thus, $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

*Is this a valid proof?*

Comment: The proof is not valid. You need to justify why $2$ not being a perfect square implies irrationality.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to first establish that $\sqrt{a}$ is irrational if and only if $a$ is a perfect square.  (Is this obvious?)  Then you could kick in your argument.

Comment: No, I'm afraid it isn't.  You've proved that $2$ is not the square of an integer, but you need to prove that $2$ is not the square of a rational number.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot

Comment: @saulspatz  has hit the real issue.

Comment: Also you need to *rigorously prove* your claim about the form of perfect squares, which requires using both the *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations of integers. Your proof is likely incorrect (or incomplete) if you haven't explicitly invoked both of those properties (or some lemma that does).

Comment: No.  That is a proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is not an *integer*.  Not that $\sqrt{2}$ is not *rational*.

Comment: I think a lot of the answers and comments are missing the actual *mistake* the OP made.  Which is that the unique prime factorization refers to *integer* factorization.  $2 = 2^1$ is not a perfect square and so $\sqrt{2}$ will not be an integer and $2 = (\sqrt{2})^2$ with an even power will not be an *integer* factorization.  But none of that  says anything about whether $\sqrt{2}is rational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

....

> Therefore, the prime factorization of 2 contains an odd exponent so 2 is not a perfect square.

Right. But that only goes to prove that if $\sqrt{2}^2 = 2$, then $\sqrt{2}$ is not an *integer*.  We need to prove it is not a *rational* number.

And if you want to use your theorem:

If $\sqrt{2} = \frac ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers, means that $2 = \frac {a^2}{b^2}$ which means that $2b^2 = a^2$.

Now $b^2$ is perfect square.  So it's prime factorization has only even powers.  So the power of $2$ that factors into $b^2$ is even.  (If $b$ is odd then $0$ is an even number).  So the power that divide into $2b^2$ will be $1$ higher.

So the power of $2$ that divides into $2b^2$ is odd.  So $2b^2$ is *not* a perfect square.

But $2b^2 = a^2$ so it *is* a perfect square.

That's a contradiction. So our assumption that there are integers $a,b$ so that $\sqrt{2}=\frac ab$ can't be true.  So $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational.

.....

Or maybe our theorem that *A number is a perfect square if and only if its prime factorization contains only even exponents* is incorrect.

It *is* correct and we *can* use it but we *do* have to prove it before we take it for granted.

..... PS .....

Note:  By your theorem for any prime $p$ then and integer $n$ we can see $pn^2$ is not a perfect square and indeed of any non-square $j$ then $jn^2$ can not be a perfect square.

..... PPS......

Throughout all of this we assume that there *is* such a thing as "$\sqrt{2}$".  There might not be.  After all if we are dealing with real numbers there is no such thing as $\sqrt{-1}$.  And if we are dealing with complex numbers there is no such thing as $\sqrt{\text{Babar, the elephant}}$.

It doesn't matter now, but later it will.

Our proof isn't really that "$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational" but that "if we define $\sqrt{2}$ as the number $r$ so that $r^2 = 2$ then either $\sqrt{2}$ does not exist at all or that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational", or to put in more legitimately "There is no *rational* number $r$ so that $r^2 = 2$".

To prove that there *is* a *real* number $r$ so that $r^2 = 2$ is a whole other kettle of fish.

Comment: +1 for your concluding remarks (and the funny square root of Babar).

Answer (score 1):

For such a conclusion to be established, you need to prove why $\sqrt{a}$ is always irrational whenever the prime factorization of $a$ has an odd exponent, where $a$ is a positive integer greater than $1$. (Remember a unique prime factorization is guaranteed for every positive integer by Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic)
Let's assume:
$$\sqrt{a}=\frac{p}{q}\ \{\gcd(p,q)=1\ \&\ p,q\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}^+\}$$
Here we are assuming $\sqrt{a}$ is rational and so must have a simplest form. Thus:
$$\Rightarrow a=\frac{p^2}{q^2}\Rightarrow p^2=aq^2 $$
Since $p^2$ must have a prime factorization with only even exponents, $a$ must be have a prime factorization with only even exponents too. If we had defined $a$ as a natural number that is not a perfect square and has an odd exponent in its prime factorization than such a situation is absurd (Reductio ad absurdum) and we have proved what we set out to using proof by contradiction. Now let's say $a$ is prime (in the case of $a=2$) we can take the proof further by writing:
$$\Rightarrow a |\ p^2 \Rightarrow a |\ p$$
The last statement can be proved using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Its proof is given [elsewhere in stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921953/prove-that-if-p-is-a-prime-a-is-an-integer-and-p-divides-a2-then-p). Now that we know $a|\ p$, $p$ must be of form $ak$ for some $k\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}^+$. Thus:
$$p^2 = aq^2 \Rightarrow a^2 k^2 = aq^2 \Rightarrow q^2 = ak^2 (\because a \neq 0)$$
$$\Rightarrow a\ |\ q^2 \Rightarrow a\ |\ q \Rightarrow a\ |\ \gcd (p,q)\ (\because a\ |\ p) \Rightarrow a\ |\ 1 \Rightarrow a=1$$
But we had defined $a$ to be a positive integer greater than 1. Reductio ad absurdum.
Therefore $\sqrt{a}$ can only be rational if $a$ is a perfect square.

Comment: To make the first proof completely rigorous requires making *explicit* the many implicit uses of the *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations. A note on style: in proofs involving primes the symbols $p$ and $q$ usually denote primes, so it may cause confusion to use them more generally (here arbitrary coprimes)

Comment: @BillDubuque I have assumed a lot of lemmas and theorems to be true in this one, assuming the reader must have a fair knowledge of number theory problems. Thanks for noticing about the variables, I felt the same, but thought it's okay since I defined each one in my way. It'd be great if you could change some of the variables as per convenience (like $x, y, z$) This is unrelated, but Im a big fan of your bio on stack exchange...:)

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your argument is not a full proof.

However, unique factorization is strong and can easily prove that $\sqrt2$ is irrational. But sometimes we want a proof that does not use such an "expensive" theorem.

But to repair/complete your proof, you *could* generalize the fact from the other thread (which I think was about whole numbers only) into something like:

> A rational number $a$ is the square of some (other) rational number
>   if and only if (after reducing the fraction $a$ to lowest terms if necessary)
>   the prime factorizations of both the numerator of $a$ and the denominator of $a$
>   contain only even exponents.

If we take *unique factorization* (fundamental theorem of arithmetic) for known, it is easy to prove this statement. (Go ahead.)

Then write "two" as $a=\frac21$. While the denominator $1$ is OK (all primes are to the zeroth power, and zero is even), the numerator $2=2^1$ has an odd exponent, and so $\frac21$ is not the square of any fraction.

Comment: "Unique factorization is strong and can easily prove that 2–√ is irrational. But sometimes we want a proof that does not use such an "expensive" theorem."  This implies the OPs proof was valid.  Which it was not.

Comment: We don't need full-blown unique factorization, only the much simpler  uniqueness of the prime $\,2,\,$ i.e. every integer $> 0$ can be written *uniquely* in the form $\, 2^{\large k} n\,$ for odd $\,n.\,$  [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1885486/242) for more.

Comment: @fleablood It was not my intention to say his proof was valid and complete. I wanted to say that you _can_ prove it with an idea along these lines. The rest of my post tries to give details.