# The proof of $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The classic proof of $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational starts with the assumption that
$\sqrt{2}$ can be represented as a rational number $\frac pq$
where $(p,q \in \Bbb Z , q\neq 0$, p and q are coprimes)

$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{2^2}=\frac {p^2}{q^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow 2q^2 = p^2$$
Since, $$2|p^2 \Rightarrow 2|p$$
$$\Rightarrow p= 2r$$ where, $(r \in \Bbb Z)$
$$\Rightarrow 2q^2=(2r)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow q^2 = 2r^2$$
Since, $$2|q^2 \Rightarrow 2|q$$
since p and q have a common factor of 2, this contradicts the statement that p and q are coprimes and hence our assumption that $\sqrt2$ is rational is incorrect which implies that $\sqrt2$ is irrational.
While this argument is pretty reasonable,

I think it can be shortened, in the second line of the proof (i.e. $2q^2=p^2$)
since p and q are coprimes they don't share any common prime factors, and since p is an integer which is divisible by 2, its square (i.e. $p^2$) must have an even number of 2s but as we can see it only has one factor of $2$ (i.e.$2q^2=p^2$) which implies that $p$ is not an integer
which is a contradiction to the given statement that $p$ is an integer. Hence $\sqrt2$ is an irrational number.

Please correct me if this proof is wrong.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2970868/977780 here you will find your answer and you can verify it by your own

Comment: The standard proof requires you to know that if $p$ is prime and $p\mid a^n$ for some $n,$ then $p\mid a.$ Unique factorization might let you shorten the proof, but unique factorization is in some ways a fairly complicated theorem. Try writing out what unique factorization means, and notice you end up with the dreaded ellipsis “$\dots$“ in a product. In first order Peano arithmetic, it is particularly hard to write out unique factorization. It is not even remotely obvious that it can be written - it seems to require the result that “exponentiation is diophantine” to write it out.

Comment: So, it is *slightly* shorter using unique factorization, but with a boatload of hidden complications.

Comment: Your shorter form is a variant of a well-known proof  - compare the *parity* of the powers of $2$ on both sides, using FTA (existence & uniqueness of prime factorizations), e.g. see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2441234/242) in the linked dupe. As emphasized there we don't even need the very strong FTA theorem, only the much simpler result that every natural can be written uniquely in the form $\,2^i n\,$ for $\,n\,$ odd, which has a short simple proof.

Comment: Note that in the linked form of the proof we don't even need to assume $p$ and $q$ are coprime - the parity mismatch still works even in the non-coprime case.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162122/242) for how to generalize this style of proof to show that the square-root of any nonsquare is irrational, and see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4467/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91538/242) for many  other irrationality proofs and generalizations.

Answer (score 0):

The proof you suggest uses (two particular cases of) the fundamental theorem of arithmetic: 1) the product of two odd numbers is odd, and 2) a product of $2$ and an odd number cannot be divisible by $4$. Both facts are easy to prove without FToA, but the proof will be longer than the  standard proof of the statement.

Note that 1) but not 2)   is used implicitly in the standard proof too.